# Audiveris Setup - Java web start (jnlp)

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm trying to set up Audiveris, an open-source OMR software, and am struggling to make sense of what is going on in the installation. The problem is that it is trying to pull tesseract from the deprecated google site, as opposed to where it is currently located (on github).

[image: Installation fails on step 4]

I tried looking through the JNLP file (Java Web Start) that launches the app, however I am confused as to what the hrefs are referring to. Is there a simple solution to specify the correct path to tesseract by changing the JNLP?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- from audiveris/master-application.jnlp --><jnlp codebase="https://audiveris.kenai.com/jnlp" href="launch.jnlp" spec="7.0+" version="4.3">    
    <information>
        <title>Audiveris</title>
        <vendor>Audiveris Ltd.</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://audiveris.kenai.com"/>
        <description>Optical Music Recognition software</description>
        <description kind="short">Audiveris</description>
        <icon href="resources/icon-64.png"/>
        <icon href="resources/splash.png" kind="splash"/>
        <shortcut install="true" online="true">
            <desktop/>
            <menu/>
        </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
    <!-- check: always, timeout(default), background -->
    <!-- policy: always(default), prompt-update, prompt-run -->
<!--    <update check="always" policy="prompt-update" />-->
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <!--        <java version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-Xms384m -Xmx384m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>      -->
        <!-- ???    <java version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-Xms384m -Xmx384m -verbose:class" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/jawsautodl/AutoDL/j2se" />-->
        <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Xms384m -Xmx384m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" version="1.7+"/>    
        <!-- Logging -->
<!--        <property name="logback.configurationFile" value="config/logback.xml" />-->
        <!-- eager download after this line -->
        <jar href="audiveris.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/Jama-1.0.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/bsaf-1.9.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/crystal-icons.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/eventbus-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jcip-annotations.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/logback-classic-1.0.11.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/logback-core-1.0.11.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jgoodies-common-1.6.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jgoodies-forms-1.7.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jgoodies-looks-2.5.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/javacpp.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/tesseract-3.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jai_imageio.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/clibwrapper_jiio.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jai_core.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jai_codec.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/mlibwrapper_jai.jar"/>        
        <!-- lazy download after this line -->
        <!-- Used for printing score -->
        <jar download="lazy" href="lib/iText-5.0.4.jar" part="pdf"/>
        <package name="com.itextpdf.*" part="pdf" recursive="true"/>
        <!-- Used for scale charts -->
        <jar download="lazy" href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar" part="chart"/>
        <jar download="lazy" href="lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar" part="chart"/>
        <package name="org.jfree.*" part="chart" recursive="true"/>
        <!-- Used for score marshalling -->
        <jar download="lazy" href="lib/proxymusic-3.0.jar" part="marshalling"/>
        <package name="com.audiveris.proxymusic.*" part="marshalling" recursive="true"/>
        <!-- Link to Audiveris bundle installer -->
        <extension href="installer.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
    <!-- 
        For Windows, native libs are no longer kept in Java cache but 
        installed into proper Windows system folder by Installer.
    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <nativelib href="lib/tess-windows-64bit.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="lib/tess-windows-32bit.jar"/>
    </resources>
    -->
    <resources arch="amd64" os="Linux">
        <nativelib href="lib/tess-unix-64bit.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources arch="i386 x86" os="Linux">
        <nativelib href="lib/tess-unix-32bit.jar"/>
    </resources>
<!--    
    <resources os="Mac\ OS\ X" arch="x86_64">  
    </resources>  
        <resources os="Mac\ OS\ X" arch="i386 x86">  
        </resources>
    -->    
    <application-desc main-class="Audiveris">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: 1) By 'OMR' do you mean 'OCR'? 2) *"Is there a simple solution to specify the correct path to tesseract by changing the JNLP?"* Unless you intend to host the app. from your own server, there is no advantage to be gained from changing things in the JNLP launch file. The JWS launcher will typically refer back to the original version on the server. But what do you mean by *"correct path to tesseract"*? Is the path wrong? If so, you'll need to get whoever deployed it, to correct the path in the launch file.

Comment: Yup, optical music recognition is a type of OCR I believe, I should have specified. I don't know where the jar files are pointing to - the installer tries to grab tesseract from a broken link, this is probably in the jar?